# Django Login Change Index Page

Tags: django, django-templates

After log-in I want the index page to be a little different. With my menus more related to the users profile etc.

Whats the best technique do this?

My ideas are:

- Simply using template tags on the index page that show different things depending on the user log-in status. This would need some kind of just refresh after log-in. (?)
- Using different two different index-pages and write a view that checks if the user is logged in or not.
- Login with ajax and return a success-message and use some Jquery to change the index. I guess this would not be saved if I refresh the page?

Other ways? What would you recommend? It's a dynamic website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like this. Your user variable should be in the context.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   Here you can put your specific area for logged in users. Or even load etmplates.
{% else %}  
       Here you can have the basic site.        
{% endif %}
```

You can just redirect the user to the index page after successful login, and put some message in the context to display on the index site. Like I do it I don't send any message, just switch out the Login and Register buttons at my user area for Logout and user profile buttons.

Then structure your site with base template that covers the user area (and the area when users are not logged in) and load your content into different `blocks` with child `templates`.